# Numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{D}$

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory

Consider numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{D}$.
Particularly when $D=-1$, these numbers are called complex numbers and $i=\sqrt{D}$ is the imaginary unit.
Further, $a$ is called the real part, and $b$ is called the imaginary part (of the complex number).

My question is: how is the $D$ generally called?
And a supplementary question: how should the $\sqrt{D}$, $a$, $b$, and the numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{D}$ be called in the general case?

Comment: $D$ is called the radicand, and $a$ and $b$ are sometimes called the rational and irrational part - though the component names are not in very wide use. See also this [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/832170/242) about notation for the parts.

Comment: Note also that many number theorists and algebraists don't restrict "irrational" to reals but instead use the general definition irrational $:=$ not rational (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/823981/242)) so the above names work also for complex numbers.

Comment: @BillDubuque: This is actually the answer I was looking for (along with the lhf's answer below). I found that it really is being used, e.g. [here](http://www.comm.utoronto.ca/~frank/notes/complex.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't restrict $a,b$, then the numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{D}$ are exactly the real numbers when $D \ge 0$ and exactly the complex numbers when $D < 0$.

The numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{D}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt{D} \notin \mathbb Q$ are sometimes called [quadratic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_field).

The numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{D}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ are called [quadratic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer).
(Actually, there is a small difference when $D \equiv 1 \bmod 4$.)

$D$ is closely related to the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_field#Discriminant) of the quadratic field.

The components $a,b$ have no standard name when $D>0$.

Comment: Don't forget that for quadratic integers, we assume $D$ is square-free.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. However, the point of my question is: how are the individual components (especially $D$, possibly $\sqrt{D}$, $a$, and $b$) called in such cases? If necessary, we can restrict ourselves to quadratic integers.

Comment: @DaBler, see my edited answer.

Comment: @lhf: I see. Could you further extend your answer to include the terms mentioned in Bill Dubuque's comments? Then I would accept it as the answer. Thanks.